# Do JSP pages load differently than PHP on a web browser?

Tags: php, jsp, load

I know that in PHP, once you make a request, browser will go in a waiting mode until PHP does it's operation on the server and send the results back. In the meantime, there is no live connection between the browser and the Server while PHP is doing it's work.

I was wondering if same goes with JSP, or connections are handled differently?

Answer (score 0):

First of all JSP is not a programming language. It's just a technology.

I guess that your question goes more into how they work right (Java and PHP)? So to put you in a simple prespective and with a simple answer, take into consideration that both PHP and Java are scripting languages. The main difference is that Java is compiled, before going to the server, to bytecode and then that bytecode is interpreted by JVM when the request is made. On PHP the code is interpreted (translated to bytecode) on the run and executed by the server. On both cases an answer to you request is given back to browser.

On the middle in between your request and the answer, there's JSP which is a technology that makes it possible for you to write HTML with some dynamic scripting in the middle. Much like a template to something (you can also compare it to a templating engine on PHP like twig). You write it only on your views and it gets compiled by getting parsed to Java Servlets.

I hope my answer makes you investigate a little bit because it has a